# HSTS and subdomain levels

Tags: apache, security, dns, subdomain, hsts

Regarding the HSTS includeSubDomains directive. Does this include every subdomain underneath e.g. example.com. So abc.def.example.com is also included?

In the RFC:

```
The OPTIONAL "includeSubDomains" directive is a valueless directive
which, if present (i.e., it is "asserted"), signals the UA that the
HSTS Policy applies to this HSTS Host as well as any subdomains of
the host's domain name.
```

This states "any", can I take that to mean every subdomain, no matter what level. i.e. sub1.sub2.sub3.example.com not just sub3.example.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124272/does-hsts-inlcudesubdomains-directive-include-subdomains-on-all-levels

Comment: @SilverlightFox I agree! I dont know how to close it myself or would have done so.